# Is it correct to name "domino" a single domino tile?

Tags: word-usage

I was reading an article [Euroland: Will the Netherlands be the next domino to fall?](https://www.ineteconomics.org/perspectives/blog/euroland-will-the-netherlands-be-the-next-domino-to-fall) and got surprised by the usage of *domino* in the title, since it is used to mention a single piece of this game.

I had always assumed that *domino* is the game, while every piece of it is called *domino tile*.

Dictionaries say:

> [**domino**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/domino?s=t). noun, plural dominoes.
>
> 1. a flat, thumbsized, rectangular block, the face of which is divided into two parts, each either blank or bearing from one to six pips or dots: 28 such pieces form a complete set.
>
> 2. dominoes, (used with a singular verb) any of various games played with such pieces, usually by matching the ends of pieces and laying the dominoes down in lines and angular patterns.

So both definitions seem to be valid. However, is there any "default" meaning of it or will it be determined by the context?

Comment: This US English speaker has always thought of the individual piece as *a domino* and the game as *dominoes*, which seems to match what you found in the dictionary, although it's possible the usage differs in other dialects.  *Domino tile* seems stilted and overly formal.

Comment: @stangdon I was probably influenced by my mother tongue, Spanish, where _domino_ just refers to the game, while _domino_ in the sense of pices are called "pieza de dómino" (that is, _domino piece_). Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domino tiles are frequently referred to just as *dominoes* and a single tile as a *domino*. It's a common verbal shorthand.

As you are probably aware, it is possible to set up long lines of dominoes, with the tiles standing on edge, close to one another - and then, by knocking over an end tile, to cause all of the other tiles to collapse in sequence - the so-called *domino effect*.

The decision of the United Kingdom to leave the European Union is regarded by some people as the toppling of the end domino. It's not necessary to speak about the first *domino tile*. *Domino* is adequate for understanding.